# Matrix operation relating to inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Calculate matrix $B$ using the expression $AB=A^2-2A$ in which $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are given.

And of course, the first thing I was trying to do is to simplify the expression by multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides. However, the expression I get is impossible to calculate.

The following is my process, I hope someone can spot where I made a mistake!

- $AB=A^2-2A$
- $A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}A^2-2AA^{-1}$
- B = A - 2

And as you know it is impossible to do such a calculation. I am not sure where I have committed a mistake here!

Comment: Your mistake appears to be that you incorrectly interpreted $AA^{-1}$ as $1$ instead of $AA^{-1}$ as $I$.  Yes, they are both multiplicative identities, but $1$ is the multiplicative identity of the scalar field while $I$ is the multiplicative identity for the matrix ring.

Comment: So the correct one should be $B=A-2I$?

Comment: @YanZhuang Yes!

Comment: Quite.  $AB = A^2-2A$ factors as $AB = A(A-2I)$.  Left multiplying by $A^{-1}$ which you are told exists gives you $B=A-2I$

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you very much!